# Send message to specific channel with discord.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.io

With Discord.io I'm trying to send a message to a different channel than what it is sent from, but after a lot of Googling and experimenting I still can't seem to find a way to do so.

I tried to simply change the channelID to the channel I want it to send to and overide the channelID to the channel I want it to send to, but with no success

For example:

```
bot.on('message', function (user, userID, channelID, message, evt) {
    if (message.substring(0, 1) == '!') {
        var args = message.substring(1).split(' ');
        var cmd = args[0].toLowerCase();

        args = args.splice(1);
        switch(cmd) {
            case 'test':
                bot.sendMessage({
                    to: // channel id here,
                    message: 'If all went well this got sent in another channel'
                });
                break;
            default:
                bot.sendMessage({
                    to: channelID,
                    message: 'I wasn\'t able to understand this command, please try again...'
                });
                break;
        }
    }
});
```

Hopefully you can help me out.
If there is something not clear for you, feel free to ask.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you confirm that the default case works successfully, sending a message to the channel where the bot was listening?  Can you show the code you used to get the channel ID of the other channel you wish to send your message to?

Comment: @ConspicuousCompiler I already fixed the issue, but still thanks for trying to help me out. It doesn't allow me to set it as a solution yet (2 days wait?), but will do so when possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out why it didn't work, in the documentation it says channelID is Snowflake. What I didn't know is that this looks a lot like just a regular string. So when I tried to overide channelID by a string, it seemed to work. Like this:

```
bot.on('message', function (user, userID, channelID, message, evt) {
    if (message.substring(0, 1) == '!') {
        var args = message.substring(1).split(' ');
        var cmd = args[0].toLowerCase();

        args = args.splice(1);
        switch(cmd) {
            case 'test':
                bot.sendMessage({
                    to: 'your channel id here',
                    message: 'If all went well this got sent in another channel'
                });
                break;
            default:
                bot.sendMessage({
                    to: channelID,
                    message: 'I wasn\'t able to understand this command, please try again...'
                });
                break;
        }
    }
});
```